# After a restart I am forced to run `ecryptfs-mount-private`, preventing proper use of the PC

Tags: display-resolution, amd-graphics, reboot

I am using Ubuntu 20.04:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Until today my PC had been running well, with the occasional freeze that prompted a restart. Today after restarting my PC, I found that I need to run `ecryptfs-mount-private` to access my files.

```
PC:~$ ls
Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop  README.txt
PC:~$ cat README.txt 
THIS DIRECTORY HAS BEEN UNMOUNTED TO PROTECT YOUR DATA.

From the graphical desktop, click on:
 "Access Your Private Data"

or

From the command line, run:
 ecryptfs-mount-private
PC:~$ ecryptfs-mount-private
Enter your login passphrase:
Inserted auth tok with sig [...] into the user session keyring

INFO: Your private directory has been mounted.
INFO: To see this change in your current shell:
  cd /home/name
```

This is also causing other side effects such as being locked on 1024x768 resolution (my monitor is 1080p), and in settings there is no option to change it. Ubuntu also fails to detect my second monitor.[image]

Another side effect is that many settings have been reverted back to the Ubuntu default, for example I have Thunderbird in my dock as a favorite app, and not apps which I previously made favorite.

What are the next steps to take in trying to solve this problem? What other info should I provide?

Comment: Oh... if you have to mount your home directory by hand, then it can't find your settings, including your resolution. However, as far as I know that should not prevent you from changing back to 1920x1080. At this point, I would focus my effort in fixing the `ecryptfs-mount-private` issue.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Thanks for the insight. Should I make a new post or edit this one?

Comment: Editing this one will certainly work just fine.